# VT-resize (great alternative to timthumb) : Errors cropping (litespeed, centos 6.3)

Tags: images, timthumb, cropping

I'm using from several months wt-resize, a script to resize images on the fly. It works very well until now...

I've changed hosting provider. I'm using now Centos 6.3 (no control panel) + Litespeed (php 5.4.11) and i have following errors:

```
Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in     /home/*****/***/
 Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/
```

According source page where i see this error it seems that this script isn't able anymore to return the name of the file.

Do you have any workaround ?

I'm asking about this script because Wordpress doesn't resize images on the fly. If you add to functions.php a new size, for example

```
add_image_size( 'archivio', 250, 140, true );
```

you resize every single image you upload online to the size 250x140 and i'm interested only to resize what i want

Here's the error i have on the source page where i'm using this script

```
 <b>Warning</b>:  getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in       <b>/home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***-v16/functions.php</b> on line <b>139</b><br   />
 <br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
 <b>/home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***-v16/functions.php</b> on line <b>140</b>
 <br />
 <img src="http://www.***.com/images/2013/02/" width="" height="" />
</a>
```

For reference: https://gist.github.com/seedprod/1367237/raw/acf4a2987ff07da6135ac2a91df5532b855ccb46/vt_resize.php

More details:

Previous server configuration was Centos 6.3 + Nginx + PHP 5.3.2.1. I can confirm this script was working well :(

Comment: Do you use the same Versions of WordPress on both Setups? Do you have the same Directory Permissions set for your System?

Comment: 1)Do you use the same Versions of WordPress on both Setups? 
Yes, latest wp available for download


2)Do you have the same Directory Permissions set for your System?
* No. WIth virtualmin i was using standard user. Now i'm using ftpuser:nobody for files inside public_html

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here lies within the Plugin, which utilizes the deprecated Function `image_resize`. I'm not 100% sure that this is the only Problem, but try rewriting the Plugin using the new `[WP_Image_Editor][1]` Class.

The next Step to check is if the Plugin can write the files, and if the directory permissions are set correctly.

See Line 128 of your code:

```
$new_img_path = image_resize( $file_path, $width, $height, $crop );
```

This line returns a String if executed correctly, or an `WP_Error` Object on Failure. I'm pretty sure this is where your Plugin goes wrong.

If you do not want to rewrite it (which I highly recommend), try writing a small Plugin to find out if your `image_size` works as expected, or if you have to change your Server's settings.

For the Image functions to work, you have to have your `Uploads` Directory writeable for your Plugin Files.

Comment: wow thanks for reply :) Unfortunately i know only how to setup a server, permissions and so on but i don't know nothing about php programming.
Your reply is  illuminating. It means i must search some workaround because without this function = more mess on hdd (hundred images never used) :)

Comment: The function `image_resize` actually saves the Thumbnail into your `Uploads` directory, you are aware of that, aren't you?

Comment: I'm aware what you are saying about this function 100% but i confirm i was using this functions for a different url (i'm saving the images from years on http://mysite.com/images.) and worked well since last year (october).

http://pastebin.com/fFtVBGHP

(sry, too much long for a cut & paste there)

Comment: Okay, nice. just wanted to point it out :)